# Can I query MongoDB to get all items in collection, starting at specific index?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that is being returned to my front end as an array. Right now, my query is is getting all items with a specific category_Id. Everything is returning as expected.

Problem: I need to be able to get the results into the front end (angularJS), with the array beginning at a specific point in the results, instead of beginning at the 0 index or first result every time.

Example:
Query returns results in array; [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...500]. Results get populated in view with ng-repeat at 0, 1, 2, etc. How do I get the ng-repeat to start at [347], for example?

View:

```
<div class="col m12" dir-paginate="material in scrollStuff | itemsPerPage: 1">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h5 class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{{ material.material_name }}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <img class="activator" ng-src="http://marble.com/uploads/materials/{{material.material_id}}/1280X720/{{material.material_photo_name}}">
              </div>
              <div class="card-reveal" id="reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><h3>{{ material.material_name }}</h3><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p><strong>Description: </strong>{{ material.material_description }}</p>
                <p><strong>Other Names: </strong>{{ material.material_other_names }}</p>
                <p><strong>Country of Origin ID: </strong>{{ material.material_country_of_origin }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Query:

```
app.get('/material/:id', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('moreInfoPhotos').find({"material_category_id": req.params.id}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use the cursor's [**`skip()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#skip) method though on the server it is often expensive, slower and more CPU intensive because it requires the server to walk from the beginning of the collection or index to get the offset or skip position before beginning to return results.

Comment: This works in the sense that it starts the results at whatever place your choose. However, it's still just returning an array starting at [0]. What I am trying to accomplish is for the user to be able to click back and forth through the results. So, user clicks [245], view renders [245], but there is still an array of [0...500] that the user can click back and forth through... Did I explain that well enough?